# Provide implicit evidence for a type alias in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, higher-kinded-types

Is there a way to get the compiler to somehow consider type aliases when looking for implicit evidence?

Here is an example of problem I am trying to solve:

```
// Third party library
class Foo[T, P]
class FooOps[FTP, T] {
  def apply[F[_, _], P](t: T)(implicit ev: F[T, P] =:= FTP): FTP = ???
}

type StringFoo = Foo[String, Boolean]
object StringFoo extends FooOps[StringFoo, String]

StringFoo("hello")

// Attempt to wrap the third party type but have the same ops
class WrappedFoo[FTP](val foo: FTP)
object WrappedFoo {
  type F[T, P] = WrappedFoo[Foo[T, P]]
}

type WrappedStringFoo = WrappedFoo[StringFoo]
object WrappedStringFoo extends FooOps[WrappedStringFoo, String]

WrappedStringFoo("hello") // Cannot prove that F[String, P] =:= WrappedStringFoo
WrappedStringFoo[WrappedFoo.F, Boolean]("hello”) // This works
```

I don't quite understand how the compiler infers the types in:

```
StringFoo("hello")
```

Does it somehow use the available implicits to choose a value for `F[_, _]`? I always thought that it had to work out the types first.

However it works for `StringFoo` it doesn't work for `WrappedStringFoo`. Likely since the number of type parameters is different.

How can I get:

```
WrappedStringFoo("hello")
```

to compile without specifying the types explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add necessary implicit to scope:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

class Foo[T, P]
class FooOps[FTP, T] {
  def apply[F[_, _], P](t: T)(implicit ev: F[T, P] =:= FTP): FTP = ???
}

type StringFoo = Foo[String, Boolean]
object StringFoo extends FooOps[StringFoo, String]

class WrappedFoo[FTP](val foo: FTP)
object WrappedFoo {
  type F[T, P] = WrappedFoo[Foo[T, P]]

  //implicit val ev0: WrappedFoo.F[String, Boolean] =:= WrappedStringFoo = ???
  implicit val ev0: WrappedFoo.F[String, Boolean] =:= WrappedStringFoo = 
    null.asInstanceOf[WrappedFoo.F[String, Boolean] =:= WrappedStringFoo]
}

type WrappedStringFoo = WrappedFoo[StringFoo]
object WrappedStringFoo extends FooOps[WrappedStringFoo, String]

WrappedStringFoo("hello")
```

When you do `StringFoo("hello")` compiler solves equation `F[String, P] = Foo[String, Boolean]` and it's smart enough to deduce `P = Boolean`, `F = Foo`. But when you do `WrappedStringFoo("hello")` compiler has to solve equation `F[String, P] = WrappedFoo[Foo[String, Boolean]]` and algorithms it uses are not smart enough to deduce `P = Boolean`, `F = ({ type λ[A, B] = WrappedFoo[Foo[A, B]] })#λ` i.e. `WrappedFoo.F` (and possibly such equations can't be solved in general if they are advanced enough). So you should provide a hint. Either specifying type parameters explicitly or providing necessary implicit evidence.

Resolving implicits and type inference make impact on each other. You can read section 4.4.3 of Eugene Burmako's [thesis](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/226166/files/EPFL_TH7159.pdf#subsection.4.4.3).